# Difference between N[CDF[NormalDistribution[m,s],x]] and CDF[NormalDistribution[m,s],x]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm new to Mathematica and I am struggling with the following problem:

If I evaluate the expression `N[CDF[NormalDistribution[m,s],x]]` for `m=12`, `s=25` and `x=10`, i get `0.468119` (=the value I would expect), however, if I evaluate the expression `CDF[NormalDistribution[m,s],x]` for the same `x,m,s`, i get `0.324195`.

I checked the documentation for Mathematica and I cannot spot the difference except that `N[..]` returns the numerical value of the expression inside the brackets.

Any ideas? Perhaps its soo simple but i don't see it..
Thank you

Comment: `CDF[NormalDistribution[12, 25], 10]` gives `1/2 Erfc[Sqrt[2]/25]`. How are you getting `0.324195`?

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks a lot for your reply. I rechecked the sheet and I expected what you posted. Perhaps a bug of some sort.. I cross checked it with a short script in VBA and get the same values. Would anyone be so kind and please set this question to "closed"? Thanks!